# Cannot select individual caption in premier timeline

Tags: closed-captioning

I have just added an SCC file to my premier project.  I can see each caption "box" in the timeline, including the handles.  However, if I try to drag the handle of one caption box left or right, it moves all of the captions as a group.  I cannot unlink them.  Advice?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot? I'm having similar issues, but not exactly the same. Premiere seems to have some problems when it comes to editing captions.